Which part is considered 'parsing' of a response, and what is the other complimentary part called?
Consider the following generic examples of web scraping code
# 1. Sending a request
url = 'https://example.com'
response = requests.get(url)

# 2. 'Parsing' of the response
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

# 3. Even more 'parsing' of the already 'parsed' response
data_1 = [x.text for x in soup.find_all('a')]
data_2 = [x.text for x in soup.find_all('b')]

# 1. Sending a request
url = 'https://anotherexample.com'
response = requests.get(url)

# 2. 'Parsing' of the response
response_json = response.json()

# 3. Even more 'parsing' of the already 'parsed' response
data_1 = r_json['items']
data_2 = r_json['other_items']

I have seen parts 2 and 3 - individually and collectively - referred to as 'parsing' of the initial response. But both parts serve very different functions and it is often useful to separate them into different functions/etc.
This creates a bit of uncertainty when naming the functions in as descriptive a way as possible, or giving a 'name' to the type of underlying logic in each function - if I refer to part 2 as 'parsing' then part 3 can only be referred to as 'further parsing'. So is there more suitable, 'separate' terminology for what we are doing in parts 2 and 3?

You can consider part 2 as parsing_responose and part 3 as extracting_required_data_from_parsed_response. Again, part 3 can be differentiated in 2 ways.


extracting_required_data_from_parsed_html


extracting_required_data_from_parsed_dict




So is there more suitable, 'separate' terminology for what we are doing in parts 2 and 3?

I'd say the following would be pretty customary:

sending request
reading response,
parsing response data.

Namely, we typically use "reading" (to raw
data) from a channel or a file; "parsing" (from raw data) to domain
representations (e.g. domain objects).
That said, synonyms could be used at different levels of abstraction (e.g. reading vs deserializing), what is fixed there is that, as said, we are distinguishing the operation of reading and maybe decoding from a channel to raw data from that of parsing from raw data into domain representations, which are not only conceptually but usually technically altogether different (different "channels" but also different protocols/parsing rules).
